# How does one activate viscosity change, in gap flow, as the dependency (field variable) is specified at a particular node in Abaqus Standard?

Tags: abaqus

I have a question regarding fluid flow and the change in viscosity of the fluid flow as the field parameter changes from one step to another.

I am modelling fluid flow, followed by fluid and proppant flow inside a cohesive fracture. In step 2, I just pump in normal fluid (that has low viscosity of 1 cP) and at the beginning of step 3, I am assigning to a particular node a field variable number so that the viscosity of the fluid will change from 1 cP to 3cP at the start of step 3. Thus, what I am doing is the following:

Under *Gap Flow keyword,

I am entering the following lines:

> *Gap Flow, dependencies=1
>
> 0.001, ,   0.
>
> 0.00122408, , 0.05
>
> 0.00153288, ,  0.1
>
> 0.00558678, ,  0.3
>
> 0.0187778, ,  0.4

Under *Step keyword (when it is step 3),

I am entering the following line:

> *FIELD, VARIABLE=1
>
> Part-1-1.inlet_Node, 0.273

"Part-1-1.inlet_Node" is the node where I am injecting the fluid, using the command *cflow at the beginning of step 2.

When step 3 will start, I want Abaqus to change the fluid viscosity because I am introducing the field variable at this node. Basically, I am trying to tell Abaqus that I am injecting fluid with proppants mixed with them at the beginning of Step 3, which will result in the higher pressure gradient accross the fracture length!!!

But when I do this, for some reason, this change is not taking place! The pressure change, due to injecting viscous fluid, is not taking place!

Could you please help me with this? Maybe I am doing this wrong!

Comment: Either you are assigning a property change as per your second paragraph or you are injecting more fluid as per the last but one paragraph... Which are you doing and which do you want to do?

Comment: I am simulating proppant transport inside a fracture in the reservoir in Abaqus Standard. I have 3 steps: geostatic, injecting clean fluid (0 proppants in fluid), then injecting slurry (liquid has proppants in it). I have used *gap flow to tell abaqus I am injecting fluid into the cohesive fracture. I have used a dependency (which is the volumetric concentration of proppants in the fluid) to correlate viscosity of the fluid flowing inside the fracture to the amount of proppants being injected. But, Abaqus is somehow ignoring this relation, since it isn't getting reflected in pressure changes.

Comment: I am using the property change, or at least, i am trying to! But it doesn't work!